# ViewBag Iteration Problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I get the message "'object' does not contain a definition for 'id' when iterating over a ViewBag object:

```
@foreach (var f in ViewBag.FundsCenters)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@f.id
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Yet in the Immediate Window I see:

```
@f
{ id = 0, center = Top-Level, title = title, amount = 0 }
    amount: 0
    center: "Top-Level"
    id: 0
    title: "title"
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamics don't translate well across domain boundaries. ViewBag is meant for stuff like the title of the page or some simple message and not meant to be used otherwise.

If you really want to use this (assuming it's not an anonymous object) you can cast `f` to the type of object it is. `@(((FundCenter)f).id)` otherwise the best advice is to pass it in to the page using your model.

Answer (score 0):

The items in the loop are case sensitive. E.G

@item.firstName is not the same as @item.FirstName in this case... So if your model is f.Id perhaps instead of f.id you will get an error.

same thing goes when your biding a model with knockout.